# Having issues with CSS border-radius

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I am adding the following code to my CSS file for my parent div .outertContainer but the border-radius is only affecting the top two corners and not the bottom two corners. I cannot seem to figure it out. Everything else seems to work fine.

```
   *{
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.outerContainer{
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 9px;
  top:23%;
  right: 10%;
  width:30%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
}

.input-form-control{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
::placeholder {
  color: #99a3a4;
}
.submit-btn{
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  width: 92%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  
}
```

The following is the html code:

```
<div className="LoginPage">
     
        <div className="outerContainer">
                <form name="form">
                    <div className="emailLabelInput">
                        <input type="text" className="login-form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email address"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="passwordLabelInput">
                        <input type="password" className="login-form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button className="submit-btn">Log in</button>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Could you post the html and css for the parent and its children?

Comment: I added the complete css code

Comment: We still need the html to do much troubleshooting

Comment: Okay I just added the html as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you have `* { background: white; }` which makes the background of all the elements white. Since the `form` is just as large as the `outerContainer` and does NOT have a `border-radius`, it effectively covers up the `border-radius` applied to the `outerContainer`. So you have two options to fix the problem:

1 — Remove `* { background: white; }`. This works for the most part except that the two inputs are still positioned in the top left corner of the `outerContainer` and of course still covering that corner. If you have those positioned a little differently, this would work.

2 — Add `padding: 10px` to the `outerContainer`. This will give the `outerContainer` a little bit of 'breathing room' and keep the `form` from covering the corners. See the snippet below.

```css
*{
  background:white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.LoginPage{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}

.outerContainer{
  padding:10px; /* Added to show radius */
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 9px;
  top:23%;
  right: 10%;
  width:30%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
}

.input-form-control{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #99a3a4;
}

#error-message{
  border: 1px solid #ff7f50;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.submit-btn{
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  width: 92%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="LoginPage">
  <div class="outerContainer">
    <form name="form">
      <div class="emailLabelInput">
        <input type="text" class="login-form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email address"/>
      </div>
      <div class="passwordLabelInput">
        <input type="password" class="login-form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="submit-btn">Log In</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep that was it. By adding 10px it worked. I have accepted this answer to be correct. Thank you so much.